# Remote Event Receivers compared to server-side event receivers. Can I define a scope for them and attach them to existing lists

Tags: development, sharepoint-addin, remote-event-receiver, visual-studio-2015

I have being developing server-side event receivers for many years and for many projects. Now I want to start my first experience in developing remote event receivers inside my SP 2013 on-premises. so I create the following using VS 2015 Professional:-
1.  Create a new SP add-in. of type SharePoint hosted 
2.  Add a new event receiver which gets fired when item is being adding for “Issue Tracking” list.
Now I am facing some difficulties in understanding if these properties are available inside remote event receivers as in the server side event receiver:-

1. Can I define the scope for my remote event receiver to be “Web” or “Site”?
2. Most of the tutorials I read about which talks about remote event receivers will create a new list as part of the SharePoint add-in. so can I create a new remote event receiver which will get fired on existing lists?
3. I am not sure how I can publish my remote event receiver to my app catalogue. Now I right click on the remote event receiver inside VS 2015.then I select “New” for the current profile.  But when I click on “Create new Profile” the dialog will automatically get closed.

[image]

So I am not sure how I can publish my remote ER to my app catalogue site ?? 
so can anyone adivce on the above 3 points please?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation around Remote Event Receivers is really unfortunate. There's an opportunity for someone to write a blog post to clarify how it works in practice.

There are two components to a Remote Event Receiver:

- The web service itself
- The registration of the remote event receiver.

Note that neither of those components contains the word "App". In fact, the entire App/Add-in concept is completely unnecessary for the creation of Remote Event Receivers. The Visual Studio tooling for RERs does so in an App context, so that's what most people go with.

Just deploy your app web project as written to an Azure web site. That will handle the first component. Forget all about the app part, unless you need it to be an App for some reason.

Next, you need to register your RER with the target site. There is a neat PnP Cmdlet that does this in a one-liner:

```
Add-PnPEventReceiver -List "ProjectList" -Name "TestEventReceiver" -Url https://yourserver.azurewebsites.net/eventreceiver.svc -EventReceiverType ItemAdded -Synchronization Asynchronous
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_powershell/addpnpeventreceiver

Or, you could do it in C# CSOM:

```
EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation receiver = new 

EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation();
  receiver.EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemUpdated;
  receiver.ReceiverUrl = "https://yourserver.azurewebsites.net/eventreceiver.svc";
  receiver.ReceiverName = "My RER";
  receiver.Synchronization = EventReceiverSynchronization.Asynchronous;

  myList.EventReceivers.Add(receiver);
  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

If you need to automate this you'll need to provide a mechanism for that. I typically will wrap this into a site provisioning solution (C#) or if it needs to be applied in a one-off solution, I'll use the PowerShell.

By the way, Remote Event Receivers do not have the concept of Scope. You can think of them all as web-scoped.

edit: I've written a "starter project" that I use for remote event receivers that only includes the necessary stuff and omits all the app nonsense included with the VS template. Feel free to clone it and use it. https://github.com/dgusoff/RemoteEventReceiver.Starter

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. so now let say i create the remote event receiver using VS tooling or your "starter project".. then why do i need to deploy it inside Azure web site (which currently i do not have ) as i am working on sharepoint 2013 on-premise,,, so can I deploy the remote event receiver to my app catalog site.. and then install the remote event receiver inside my related site/s by going to "site content">>"add app">>"from your organization">>select the remote event receiver which i created ??

Comment: second question,, can i attach remote event receivers to existing lists?? or the list i want the remote event receiver to work on should be part of the VS project?as most of the tutorials i read will first add a list inside the sharepoint add-in project then they will add the remote event receiver and chose to attach it to the list?? or this is done for demonstration purposes only. and i can attach remote ER to existing lists and libraries as i do with the server-side ER?

Comment: Yep, you can attach to pre-existing lists using the code samples I provided.

Comment: so in you code sample the event receiver will be attached to any list named `ProjectList` inside the site which have the remote event receiver install on ??? second question can you advice on this part of my question as mentioned above comment... so now let say i create the remote event receiver using VS tooling or your "starter project".. then why do i need to deploy it inside Azure web site (which currently i do not have ) .....

Comment: You can deploy your web code to any web site you like. It can be in Azure, in Rackspace, in a VM inside your firewall, or in a server sitting under your desk. It doesn't matter.

Comment: ....as i am working on sharepoint 2013 on-premise,,, so can I deploy the remote event receiver to my app catalog site.. and then install the remote event receiver inside my related site/s by going to "site content">>"add app">>"from your organization">>select the remote event receiver which i created ??

Comment: If you want to deploy an app to your app catalog, then the attachment code would live in the app installed event.

Comment: so now to be honest i am a bit confused.. now i want to follow creating the remote event receiver using VS2015 as most of the documentations i found refer to this method. i agree that it might not be the ideal solution and using a starter project might be more reliable .. but now let say i create a new SP add-in, and then i add a new RER which get fired when an item is added, then the next step is to deploy it inside my app catalog.

Comment: ..now when i right click on my remote event receiver and click on publish i will be prompted with a dialog box (as shown inside the pic i provide), but when i click "new" inside the "Create new profile" the dialog will close suddenly and i am unable to publish the RER. Second question, let say i succeeded in deploying the RER into my app catalog, and then i went to a site then from "Site content">>"add app">>"from your organization">>i click on the newly added RER,

Comment: ....so does this mean that the RER will be attached to all the issue tracking lists inside my current site (host web) automatically?? assuming that when i created the RER i define that it should run when item is being added inside issue tacking lists...

Comment: This is exactly the problem with using the VS App tooling. It doesn't map well to real world situations. The code I shared attaches the RER to a single specific list.

Comment: so can you answer my 3 questions please. 1) why almost all the documentations i read about will create the remote event receivers inside sharepoint add-in? never saw any articles which uses appraoch such as the starter project you provide? 2) if i create the remote event receiver using the starter project , so i do not have to build any SP Add-in ?? so i just deploy the starter project inside IIS and using PnP script i can attach the RER to the related list/s that is all?? 3) where i need/can to deploy the RER can i deploy it inside the same IIS where SP is deployed to minimize HW code?

Comment: fourth question i read more about the starter project but i have noted this limitation `If you need to use the security context of the current user, this solution does not support that. I'll gladly accept contributions from anyone who wishes to attempt to implement this.` .. so does this mean that if i use the starter project i will not be able to run the remote event receiver using the current user account ? and the remote event receiver will always run under the system account ?

Comment: That's correct, there's no current user security context in my solution. You might need the app if you intend to do that. I can't answer why no one else uses the approach I take. Maybe it just doesn't work for them. Maybe they haven't thought of it.

Comment: or maybe because User context is an essential for app...